# (Edit) How to dll export a template specialization in Windows, with the source declared in a cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

**Edit** This question has been heavily modified

I am trying to export a template specialization from a dll that is defined in a cpp file (purely for the purpose of exporting the template).

The first attempt ("First Attempt") at this based on using dllimport/export in the header turned out to work both in compilation and at runtime however it produced a C4661 warning (no suitable definition provided for explicit template instantiation request). This is what I first asked the question on. However @AnT answer showed my mistake and I attempted to correct this with the "Second Attempt" this however also results in a warning as well.

**First Attempt**

foo.h

```
#ifndef _foo_h_ //header guard
#define _foo_h_

#ifdef EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORTS
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXTERN
#else
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXTERN extern
#endif

template<typename _Type>
class foo
{
public:
    _Type value();
};

EXAMPLE_FOO_EXTERN template class EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORT foo<int>;

#endif//_foo_h_
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

template<typename _Type> 
_Type foo<_Type>::value()
{
    return (_Type)1;
}
```

I have a piece of test code in the dll to output a value.

test.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int readValue()
{
    foo<int> test;

    return test.value();
}
```

**Second Attempt**

Going off of @AnT's note of the standard, instantiating in the cpp works but I am left with another issue (granted this is all VC-fu). Changing the code to below to make sure instantiation is done in the cpp (per standard and to get dll export working), I get a warning C4251: 'bar::value': class 'foo' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'bar'.

foo.h

```
#ifndef _foo_h_ //header guard
#define _foo_h_

#ifdef EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORTS
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXTERN
#else
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define EXAMPLE_FOO_EXTERN extern
#endif

template<typename _Type>
class foo
{
public:
    _Type value();
};

typedef foo<int> fooInt;

#ifndef EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORTS
extern template class __declspec(dllimport) foo<int>;
#endif

struct EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORT bar
{
    fooInt value;
};
#endif//_foo_h_
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

template<typename _Type> 
_Type foo<_Type>::value()
{
    return (_Type)1;
}

#ifdef EXAMPLE_FOO_EXPORTS
template class __declspec(dllexport) foo<int>;
#endif
```

I believe the bar struct is instantiating the foo template before it is instantiated in the cpp with the __declspec(dllexport). Besides the fact that "this is crazy, this is all wrong and why are you doing this", is there a way around this or is this just a peculiarity of windows dll import/export and it is what it is?

Comment: Why are you making explicit instantiation definition in a header file? This is an ODR violation waiting to happen.

Comment: **You don't explain what is that C4661 warning**. Try to use another compiler (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then you'll probably get *another* warning. But really, you'll better improve your source code.

Comment: C4661: no suitable definition provided for explicit template instantiation request. And this is purely a dll import/export issue I am trying to get around. Moving the instantiation to the cpp file as noted by @AnT is the correct way to handle it (and most other compilers should be happy with it). The reason I made that mistake in the first place was trying to get around the dllexport requirement needed for Windows dlls.

Comment: That explanation should go into your question, not as a comment

Comment: There are two basic ways to implement generic code, type erasure and reification.  Type erasure works at compile-time, reification works at runtime.  Your compiler, all C++ compilers, implement the first version.  It is a lot easier to implement when also having to deal with linking, it has a lot less restrictions on what you can do in a template.  You want reification, can't have it.  Backgrounder [is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1):

The language specification says

> **14.7.2 Explicit instantiation**
>   **9** An explicit instantiation definition that names a class template specialization explicitly instantiates the class template specialization and is an explicit instantiation definition of only those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation.

In your case your explicit instantiation definition does *not* provide an explicit instantiation definition for `foo<int>::value()`, since at the point of explicit instantiation that member is not defined yet.

The purpose of C4661 is to inform you about that issue. It is quite possible that a special treatment is applied by MSVC to `dllexport`-ed entities, which is what ultimately makes your code to link properly. But from the language point of view the issue is there.

Comment: I modified the question based on your response. See after the edit section. I was instantiating in the header for the dllexport declaration. I can handle it in the cpp but I run into other issues. For standards correctness, instantiating in the cpp will be the way I keep but just trying to clear out the other warnings at this point.